# SP13: Search Results from Document Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, search, search-results

I think I am making this harder than it is, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around the proper steps.  I have found a lot of ways to make this happen, but I am still confused.

Scenario: 
So, the scenario is that I want to have a search option that will allow search results to come from only ONE document library.

Possible Approach:

1. Create document library uploading all documents.
2. Create a Search Center Page
3. Create Search Results page (site collection level)
4. On the Search Results page - edit Search Web Part. Change the query by adding this `{searchTerms?} (contentclass:sts_listitem) path:http://<path>`  (Note: My Search Navigation is missing the vertical search bar)

OKay, this is far as I have gotten and I'm not sure if this is even right.  Plus I am not sure what would go next to test to see if it returns results only from the document library.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint 2013 you need to create a Results Source and configure query to search in particular library only and configure your Search Results Web Part to use your Results Source.

There were Search Scopes in SharePoint 2010 to achieve this. But in 2013 the Search Scopes are replaced with the "Result Source".

For details check this link:

[SharePoint 2013: Working with Result Sources to limit search results](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx)